# java elapse time isn't displaying

Tags: java

I read through previous posting and learned the following, but it still isn't working. Can anyone help me?

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
......
long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
long different  = endTime - startTime;

System.out.println("different : " + different);

long s = (different / 1000) % 60;
long m = (different / (1000 * 60)) % 60;
long h = (different / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24;
System.out.println(String.format("%d:%02d:%02d", h,m,s));
```

Why is my output time still 0:00:00?

```
[output]
different : 473
0:00:00
```

Comment: What output are you getting and what output do you expect?

Comment: Show signs after the decimal. (473/1000)%60=0.473. So 0 seconds is logical.

Comment: thanks.i know my mistake..i din know its less than 1 sec

Answer (score 3):

Because 473 ms < 1s, so you get 0:00:00.

Answer (score 1):

you are running for 473 milliseconds. that's half a second.

You are then displaying the hours minutes and seconds of execution, which is 0 for all of them.

Your output is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The output which you're getting now is logically correct one. Also display milliseconds in your print statement if you want calculate milliseconds with your time.

```
System.out.println(String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d.%03d", h,m,s,mls));
```

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
Instant now = Instant.now();
String output = Duration.between( now , 
                                  now.plus( 473 , ChronoUnit.MILLISECONDS ) )
                        .toString();
```

> PT0.473S

## Details

As others stated, 473 milliseconds is less than a second so it appears as zero whole seconds.

## ISO 8601

Do not track elapsed time using time-of-day formatting. It is ambiguous and confusing. And suffers from this kind of fractional problem depending on your format details.

Instead, use the standard [ISO 8601 format for a span of time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations): `PnYnMnDTnHnMnS` where `P` marks the beginning and `T` separates the years-months-days from the hours-minutes-seconds.

You are using troublesome old date-time classes now supplanted by the java.time classes.

## `Instant`

The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond).

```
Instant instant = Instant.now();
```

Let's simulate input data by getting a moment a few minutes in the future.

```
Instant future = instant.plus( 473 , ChronoUnit.MILLISECONDS );
```

## `Duration`

The [`Duration`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) class represents a span of time unattached from the timeline.

```
Duration duration = Duration.between( instant , future );
```

Generate a String in ISO 8601 format.

```
String output = duration.toString();
```

> PT0.473S

Internally tracked as a number of whole seconds plus a fractional second as a number of nanoseconds. So think of it as:

> Duration = ( Seconds + Nanos )

You can ask for the total number of whole seconds and the fractional second as nanoseconds.

```
long seconds = duration.getSeconds();
int nanos = duration.getNano();
```

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `.Calendar`, & `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`.

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (see [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706)).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as `Interval`, `YearWeek`, `YearQuarter`, and more.